# Moclan demographics and genetics

Tags: genetics, the-orville

In "About A Girl" we learn that,

> Every 75 years or so a Moclan female is born.

Yet not only do we later learn that

> - Bortus' mate Klyden was born female
>
>  - Their daughter was born female
>
>  - Their most famous author (under a pseudonym) Heveena was a female.

Clearly this seems indicate the original claim as wrong, although there are a number of possible resolutions:

> - The original claim was mistaken, propaganda, or a coverup.
>
>  - The child's gender was somehow influenced by Klyden's (but how does Moclan reproduction work anyway.)
>
>  - Moclans are very long-lived, and the 75 years is accurate
>  
>  - ?

## What is the correct resolution of this apparent dissonance?

Comment: It's not clear whether the scan revealed one female or more than one and Haveena was simply the closest.

Comment: I wondered the same thing...but figured I wasn't going to watch the show again so didn't care too much.  The other option I thought of was there was a typo or change in the script since 25 years seems like it could be a really good fit.

Comment: Moclans are clearly ashamed of their female children, so the "75 years" statistic may be a matter of state propaganda. This statistic combined with former females' reluctance to talk about having undergone the surgery (as Klyden suggested) is probably what reinforces their prejudice.

Answer (score 1):

Statistics can only be based on data collected, given how shameful being a female Moclan seemed to be, we can easily conclude that the actual incidence of female births is much higher than the collected statistics as the children are either hidden entirely, or surgically altered with hush money being paid to keep it off the records.

As Moclan lay eggs to reproduce, it seems likely that little to no medical intervention is required at birth, giving families plenty of time to either disappear,

> as happened to the Author,

or have the sex change procedure done, but not recorded as seems possible with

> Bortus' mate Klyden, as he was unaware of the procedure until he was examined on a Union ship rather than it being listed in any medical notes.

That's assuming the central statistic authority don't downplay the numbers themselves to ensure the status of female remains shameful. After all, if it was common enough for there to be a female in every village, then it would become clear that the disadvantages attributed to being female by the prosecution in the court case were nonsensical.

Adding any or all of these strands together could give us the discrepancy noted.

Not to mention "once every X years" is a really silly way to measure something that is probably constant per head of population. Wikipedia puts the human population in 1940 at around 2.3 Billion and 75 years (2015) later as 7.3 Billion. So something like this that happened every 75 years in 1940, would happen roughly every 25 years in 2015.